# IntelliJ Idea + Dart classes - how do I view documentation comments for a particular class

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

In VSCode you can hover over a dart class name and it will give you the documentation comments.  How do you achieve this in IntelliJ?

I'm using the community edition.

[image]

*I have tried the cmd + mouse hover but it doesn't give me the comments*

Answer (score 0):

it was an option that isn't automatically selected

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html

> Automatically show quick documentation #
>
> ```
> In the Settings/Preferences dialog (⌃⌥S), go to Editor | General.
>
> In the Other area, select the Show quick documentation on mouse move checkbox and specify the delay in milliseconds after which the
> ```
>
> popup should appear.